# Upgraded the spark version, and during spark jobs encountering java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We recently made an upgrade from Spark 2.4.2 to 2.4.5 for our ETL project.

After deploying the changes, and running the job I am seeing the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V
    at com.advisory.pic.etl.utils.OracleDialect$.<init>(OracleDialect.scala:12)
    at com.advisory.pic.etl.utils.OracleDialect$.<clinit>(OracleDialect.scala)
    at com.advisory.pic.etl.drivers.BaseDriver.$init$(BaseDriver.scala:19)
    at com.advisory.pic.etl.drivers.PASLoadDriver$.<init>(PASLoadDriver.scala:19)
    at com.advisory.pic.etl.drivers.PASLoadDriver$.<clinit>(PASLoadDriver.scala)
    at com.advisory.pic.etl.drivers.PASLoadDriver.main(PASLoadDriver.scala)
    ... 6 more
```

I read online that it could be possible due to library version mismatch, but I could not find any such violations in our build.gradle, except for **testImplementation**, which I upgraded to correct version, but I doubt this is the root cause of the issue.

Following is a snippet of dependencies in build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    def hadoopClientVersion = '2.7.1'
    def hadoopCommonsVersion = '2.7.1'
    def sparkVersion = '2.4.5'
    def sparkTestingVersion = '2.4.5'



    provided group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-client', version: hadoopClientVersion
    provided group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-common', version: hadoopCommonsVersion

    implementation("org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:$sparkVersion"){
        //excluding is causing issues when running through IDE - as sparkLibraries are not available at run-time
        //We can comment while going for deployment if we face jar conflict issues
        //exclude module: 'spark-core_2.10'
        //exclude module: 'spark-catalyst_2.10'
    }
    implementation group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.12', version: sparkVersion
    testImplementation group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.12', version: sparkVersion

    // spark -sql with avro
    implementation("com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0")

    // joda-time
    implementation 'com.github.nscala-time:nscala-time_2.12:2.22.0'

    //configuration object
    implementation group: 'com.typesafe', name: 'config', version: '1.2.1'

    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3"
    implementation "org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.13"



    // Libraries needed for scala api
    implementation 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.0'
    implementation 'org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.12.0'


    testImplementation 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12:3.0.5'

    implementation 'com.oracle:ojdbc7:12.1.0.1'

    testImplementation group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.196'

    testImplementation 'com.holdenkarau:spark-testing-base_2.12:' + sparkTestingVersion + '_0.12.0'
    itestCompile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.0'
    itestCompile 'org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12:3.0.5'
    testImplementation 'org.scalamock:scalamock_2.12:4.3.0'
}
```

Any suggestions on why the above issue is happening, and how can I verify the version mismatch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is due to mismatch between Scala version with which the code is compiled and Scala version of the runtime.

Spark 2.4.2 was prebuilt using Scala 2.12 but Scala 2.4.5 is prebuilt with Scala 2.11 as mentioned at - https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html.

This issue should go away if you use spark libraries compiled in 2.11

```
compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.11', version: '2.4.5'
```

Comment: Thank you Salim, that helped and jobs proceeded as expected. But I still have a doubt, when I looked at the documentation you linked above. I found the following: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/#:~:text=For%20the%20Scala%20API%2C%20Spark,x). Would the best approach be using 2.12.x (x is what needs to be found) Or that decision can be made based on this information: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/2.4.5 ?

Comment: Unfortunately the prebuilt Spark standalone 2.4.5 is available on Scala 2.11. We can build it using Scala 2.12 - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/building-spark.html#change-scala-version. Interestingly Databricks also supports Spark 2.4.5 with Scala 2.11 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/release-notes/runtime/6.6